# How to autowire bean in same bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I would like to autowire instance of bean A to the same instance of A. How can I achieve this with annotation (without XML).

Example:

```java
@Service
public class A {

    @Autowire
    A a;

}
```

I also tried

```java
@Service
public class A {

    A a;

    @Autowired
    public void setA(final A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

but it is not working too :-/

Configuration using XML like

```xml
<bean id="a" class="A">
    <property name="a" ref="a" />
</bean>
```

works fine. And also it's possible to use

```java
@Service
public class A implements InitializingBean {

    A a;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
    }

}
```

but this is cumbersome. The strange thing is, that Spring can handle this when using XML configuration, but not when using annotation-based one.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something here, but why do you need to do ***this***?

Comment: Because I want to call method `m()` in A from A, but also to use proxy, which is not used calling `this.m()`, for example to handle transactions (`@Transactional`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Autowired` skip the annotated bean when looking for autowire candidates, use `@Resource` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it right, and is your root problem the fact that your Transactional advice is not applied because you call a transactional method from within a non-transactional method in the same class? Can't you just extract the transactional code into another class? Isn't that more readable than this imho really weird construct?

Eg.

```
@Service
public class A {

  @Autowired B b;

  void doSomething() {
     b.m();  
  }
}

public class B {

   @Transactional
   void m() { .. }
}
```

Comment: When I have, let say, `AccountService` I want to have all methods related to account in that service and not to have `AccountServiceTransactional` and `AccountServiceWithNewTransaction`.

Comment: And what about making every method in A @Transactional? Also the method which calls m() from within A?

Comment: My service is transactional, but for some methods I want new transaction a those methods are also called from service...

Comment: and what if you set the propagation for those @Transactional methods  to Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW? Would that solve your problem?

Comment: That's the problem, when I have transactional method `service.foo()` with REQUIRED propagation and I call `service.bar()` with REQUIRES_NEW - new transaction in not created - it's not proxy call.

Comment: You can use a self reference by autowiring the service itself in the same service. That will create a transaction by using the proxy.

Comment: @Tim I'm not really sure what you meant. Is it something different compared to accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use compile-time weaving (with Aspectj compiler) so aspects do not need proxy to work.
Just add this into your pom.xml configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```