# Spring: Autowiring static self reference not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The project I am working on is a framework created in spring and is going to be packaged as jar for use in other projects.

Now, I am trying to autowire a static self referencing field. I have created a bean for the AuthenticationClient but still spring complains about not being able to find a qualifying bean to autowire. I understand wiring a static field isn't a good option. But I don't have any alternatives.

```
public class AuthenticationClient {

    private static AuthenticationClient client;
    private @Autowired KerberosAPI kerberosAPI;
    private @Autowired KerberosSessionManager kerberosSessionManager;


    public AuthenticationClient getAuthenticationClient(){
        return client;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationClient(AuthenticationClient client){
        AuthenticationClient.client = client;
    }
}
```

Servlet-Context: I have declared my beans inside the servlet-context like this

```
    <beans:bean class="com.security.kerberos.KerberosAPIImpl" />
    <beans:bean class="com.security.kerberos.model.KerberosSessionManager"/>    
    <beans:bean class="com.security.rest.client.AuthenticationClient" />
```

Detailed exception here:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.security.rest.client.AuthenticationClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**Update:**

As I told you the project is going to be packaged as jar. Now, I want to get an instance of AuthenticationClient in the controller of the project in which the jar has to be imported inn. The parent project may not be a spring project so, I need to have a way to get the instance of the AuthenticationClient without Autowiring it. The reason why I have to go on to this route. Please let me know if more information is required.

```
@Controller

public class Test {

@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public void test(){
    AuthenticationClient client = AuthenticationClient.getAuthenticationClient();
}
```

}

Comment: And where is the first instance of `AuthenticationClient` being initialised from? And is Spring aware of this instance? It seems it doesn't know of any instance of it. (By the way, setting the static instance this way is very weird)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by first instance?
I have included the beans I have declared in my servlet-context

Comment: of which type is the static field exactly? your own class `AuthenticationClient`?

Comment: Yes it is a self reference

Comment: The error is quite clear. Its saying that there should be a bean in the spring context which is of type `AuthenticationClient` but it couldn't find one. So evidently you are most probably not initialising this bean anywhere, or its not being initialised properly. Is there any other code in the class you are not showing?

Comment: My guess is that Spring cannot finish constructing the first `AuthenticationClient`, since you have an `@Autowired` setter property that relies on an already-existing instance of the same type. Surprised it can't throw a circular reference exception, though.

Comment: @Tom G There should be no problem as long it's not *constructor* injection. As for fields, Spring *tries* to wire as many fields as possible, but it will wire them still even if the refs are circular.

Comment: If I try to remove the static self reference then, the initialization works properly. So, the bean has been initialized correctly. But the problem is related to the self reference.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov Interesting, good to know.

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal Why are you using a static field anyways? If you're planning to use it in a `@Controller`, just inject it into that class directly.

Comment: @TomG My update should help in answering your questions.

Comment: If the consumer isn't a Spring project, then they'll just have to construct it manually. This is why constructor injection is preferable to field injection.

Comment: I tried creating a instance manually of the AuthenticationClient but the thing is the other Autowired fields inside the AuthenticationClient are null in that case.

Comment: If you use component scan to instantiate the service, then your servixe should be annotated with Component, Service or similar annotation. But anyway imho it's overcomplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `@Resource` annotation.

`@Autowired` skips the annotated bean itself when looking for candidates.

see [How to autowire bean in same bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279228/how-to-autowire-bean-in-same-bean)

Comment: Tried and failed! :(
I got the same exception NoUniqueBeanDefinitionFound. I guess the problem is related to the static self reference.

Comment: It worked. I had to include the name of the bean in the Resource annotation. Thanks